# GZipStream from MemoryStream only returns a few hundred bytes

Tags: c#, gzip, memorystream

I am trying to download a .gz file of a few hundred MBs, and turn it into a very long string in C#.

```
using (var memstream = new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(url)))
using (GZipStream gs = new GZipStream(memstream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var outmemstream = new MemoryStream())
{
    gs.CopyTo(outmemstream);
    string t = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outmemstream.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

My test URL: https://commoncrawl.s3.amazonaws.com/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2017-47/segments/1510934803848.60/wat/CC-MAIN-20171117170336-20171117190336-00002.warc.wat.gz

memstream has a length of 283063949. The program lingers for about 15 seconds on the line where it is initialized, and my network is floored during it, which makes sense.

outmemstream has a length of only 548.

Written to the command line is the first lines of the zipped document. They are not garbled. I'm not sure how to get the rest.

Comment: Have you verified that this works with a smaller file? Say, a megabyte or so? Are you certain that the original, uncompressed, file is UTF-8 encoded? Have you written the contents of `outmemstream` to a file to see what's in there? Are you sure you're not running out of memory? That code looks like it's going to eat up over 2 gigabytes of RAM (280 MB for the `memstream`, perhaps double that for the uncompressed data, and double that again for the string you're creating).

Comment: @JimMischel Actually it's worse than that.  The compressed data appears to be ASCII text.  1.2GB for the uncompressed data, twice that for the string representation.

Comment: Here is pull requests at dotnet/corefx:
"Add support for concatenated GZip streams. #30442"
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/30442

Comment: @StanislavPrusac The pull request #30442 has been merged. But I still see few bytes extracted only with above code in .net 4.6.1 . Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The .NET `GZipStream` unpacks the first 548 bytes of the plain text, which is all of the first record in the file.  7Zip extracts the whole file to a 1.2GB output file, but it is plain text (about 1.3 million lines worth) with no record separators, and when I test the file in 7Zip it reports 1,441 bytes.

I checked a few things and couldn't find a single compression library that would unpack this thing directly.

After a bit of casting about in the file I found that 1,441 bytes is the value of `ISIZE` which is normally the last 4 bytes of the gzip file, part of an 8-byte footer record that is appended to the compressed data chunks.

It turns out that what you have is a big set of .gz files concatenated together.  And while that's a complete pain in the butt, there are a few ways you can approach this.

The first is to scan the compressed file for the gzip header signature bytes: `0x1F` and `0x8B`.  When you locate these you will (usually) have the start of each .gz file in the stream.  You can build a list of offsets in the file and then extract each chunk of the file and decompress it.

Another option is to use a library that will report the number of bytes consumed from the input stream.  Since almost all decompressors use buffering of some sort you will find that the input stream will move much further than the number of bytes consumed, so this is difficult to guess at directly.  The `DotNetZip` streams however will give you the actual consumed input bytes, which you can use to figure out the next starting position.  This will allow you to process the file as a stream and extract each file individually.

Either way, not fast.

Here's a method for the second option, using the `DotNetZip` library:

```
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> UnpackCompositeFile(string filename)
{
    using (var fstream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        long offset = 0;
        while (offset < fstream.Length)
        {
            fstream.Position = offset;
            byte[] bytes = null;
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            using (var unpack = new Ionic.Zlib.GZipStream(fstream, Ionic.Zlib.CompressionMode.Decompress, true))
            {
                unpack.CopyTo(ms);
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
                // Total compressed bytes read, plus 10 for GZip header, plus 8 for GZip footer
                offset += unpack.TotalIn + 18;
            }
            yield return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

It's ugly and not fast (took me about 48 seconds to decompress the whole file) but it appears to work.  Each `byte[]` output represents a single compressed file in the stream.  These can be turned into strings with `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...)` and then parsed to extract the meaning.

The last item in the file looks like this:

```
WARC/1.0
WARC-Type: metadata
WARC-Target-URI: https://zverek-shop.ru/dljasobak/ruletka_sobaki/ruletka-tros_standard_5_m_dlya_sobak_do_20_kg
WARC-Date: 2017-11-25T14:16:01Z
WARC-Record-ID: <urn:uuid:e19ef645-b057-4305-819f-7be2687c3f19>
WARC-Refers-To: <urn:uuid:df5de410-d4af-45ce-b545-c699e535765f>
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 1075

{"Container":{"Filename":"CC-MAIN-20171117170336-20171117190336-00002.warc.gz","Compressed":true,"Offset":"904209205","Gzip-Metadata":{"Inflated-Length":"463","Footer-Length":"8","Inflated-CRC":"1610542914","Deflate-Length":"335","Header-Length":"10"}},"Envelope":{"Format":"WARC","WARC-Header-Length":"438","Actual-Content-Length":"21","WARC-Header-Metadata":{"WARC-Target-URI":"https://zverek-shop.ru/dljasobak/ruletka_sobaki/ruletka-tros_standard_5_m_dlya_sobak_do_20_kg","WARC-Warcinfo-ID":"<urn:uuid:283e4862-166e-424c-b8fd-023bfb4f18f2>","WARC-Concurrent-To":"<urn:uuid:ca594c00-269b-4690-b514-f2bfc39c2d69>","WARC-Date":"2017-11-17T17:43:04Z","Content-Length":"21","WARC-Record-ID":"<urn:uuid:df5de410-d4af-45ce-b545-c699e535765f>","WARC-Type":"metadata","Content-Type":"application/warc-fields"},"Block-Digest":"sha1:4SKCIFKJX5QWLVICLR5Y2BYE6IBVMO3Z","Payload-Metadata":{"Actual-Content-Type":"application/metadata-fields","WARC-Metadata-Metadata":{"Metadata-Records":[{"Value":"1140","Name":"fetchTimeMs"}]},"Actual-Content-Length":"21","Trailing-Slop-Length":"0"}}}
```

This is the record that occupies 1,441 bytes, including the two blank lines after it.

---

Just for the sake of completeness...

The `TotalIn` property returns the number of compressed bytes read, not including the GZip header and footer.  In the code above I use a constant 18 bytes for the header and footer size, which is the minimum size of these for GZip.  While that works for this file, anyone else dealing with concatenated GZip files may find that there is additional data in the header that makes it larger, which will stop the above from working.

In this case you have two options:

- Parse the GZip header directly and use `DeflateStream` to decompress.
- Scan for the GZip signature bytes starting at `TotalIn + 18` bytes.

Either should work without slowing you down too much.  Since buffering is happening in the decompression code you're going to have to seek the stream backwards after each segment, so reading some additional bytes doesn't slow you down too much.

Comment: The one thing I didn't mention: the possibility that it's not a valid gzip file. Good investigation there.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks... it was an interesting puzzle.  The fact that 7Zip extracted the whole thing was a little confusing though.  Damn those guys for being efficient :P

Comment: Multipart gzip handling appears to be implemented now in .NET Core (works on my machine with .NET 5): https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25105

Comment: @Jacob Yeah, the underlying native libraries supported it so they fixed the gzip handling in the stream wrapper. They're also adding proper zlib stream encapsulation in an upcoming release.

Comment: fstream.Position = p;
That's wrong.  p is not defined.  What should it be?

Comment: @dcarl661 Uh, yeah, that should be `fstream.Position = offset;` My bad. Over 4 years this has been up, and you're the first to spot it. Well done :P

Answer (score 3):

That is a valid gzip stream, de-compressible by gzip. Per the standard (RFC 1952), a concatenation of valid gzip streams is also a valid gzip stream. Your file is a concatenation of 118,644 (!) atomic gzip streams. The first atomic gzip stream is 382 bytes long, and results in 548 uncompressed bytes. That's all you're getting.

Apparently the `GzipStream` class has a bug in that it does not look for another atomic gzip stream after it completes the decompression of the first one, and so is not abiding by RFC 1952. You can just do that yourself in a loop, until you reach the end of the input file.

As a side note, the small size of each gzip stream in your file is rather inefficient. The compressor needs more data than that to get rolling. If that data is compressed as a single atomic gzip stream, it compresses to 195,606,385 bytes instead of 283,063,949 bytes. It would compress to about the same size even with many pieces, so long as the pieces were more like a megabyte in size or more, as opposed to the hundreds to the average 10K bytes per piece you have there.

Comment: Hi Mark.  Missed your answer, but someone just pinged me and got my attention again.  I did try a few different compression libraries and archive programs, only the 7Zip archiver let me extract the file as-is.  Seems like almost everyone assumes that only a single member exists in every file.  On Windows at least ;)